# How to check if HDFS directory is empty in Spark

Tags: api, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am using `org.apache.hadoop.fs` to check if the directory in HDFS is empty or not. I looked up the FileSystem api but I couldn't find anything close to it. Basically I want to check if directory is empty or how many files exists in it.

I was able to find "exists" method but this only tells whether the path exists or not.

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val containsFile = fs.exists(new Path(dataPath))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get ContentSummary and check count of files or directories

```
ContentSummary cs = fileSystem.getContentSummary("path");
long fileCount = cs.getFileCount();
```

Comment: Well but the ContentSummary has also `getDirectoryCount` so it might not be empty in the end

Comment: Should have used getFileAndDirectoryCount

Answer (score 1):

I would apply:

1. listFiles() from the [FileSytem class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean)), e.g.:

   FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration()).listFiles(..., true)
2. Ask if there are elements with the method hasNext() from the object returned [RemoteIterator](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/RemoteIterator.html#hasNext()).

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste solution

```
FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration()).listFiles(path, true).hasNext
```

`true` is not empty, `false` is empty